# Observe static directory for changes in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

Currently I am developing a static one page website using NodeJs, AngularJs and ExpressJS running on a Raspberry Pi. On one hand, there is the AngularJS website served by ExpressJS and showing a view images in a gallery from a static '/images' folder. On the other hand there is a cron job running on the node server to download the latest images into this folder. This background job is solved using plain javascript. But now i have the problem to publish the changes in the directory to Angular.

I have two different ideas in my mind to solve this problem. Which is the better solution for this issue and how can i accomplish?

Idea 1: Directory watcher

Create an observer in AngularJs to watch changes in the directory and update the scope variables, or

Idea 2: Update scope variables from JS

Update the used scope variables from the background task.

Any suggestions? Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would install two things to do this the right way: redis and socketio

1. When the background job adds new files to the folder, publish an event to redis.
2. In the express app, listen for events from redis then emit an event
   using socketio.
3. On your client/angular app, listen for events from socketio.

I know this seems complicated but it's actually very elegant.

Comment: sounds like a good and stable solution. I will try and report. Thanks